# strange pandas behavior: masking missing datetime index values creates duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've encountered a strange problem while trying to mask rows with missing datetime index values  using [pandas.Index.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.dropna.html). Unexpectedly, applying a mask to select only the non-missing datetime values has the consequence of duplicating identically-indexed rows.

Here is a small example which reproduces the problem (pandas 1.4.2):

```
import pandas as pd
dates = ["01-May-2022", "02-May-2022", "02-May-2022", "03-May-2022", "04-May-2022"]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
series = pd.Series(values, index=dates)
seriesB = series.loc[series.index.dropna()]

In [28]: series
Out[28]: 
01-May-2022    1
02-May-2022    2
02-May-2022    3
03-May-2022    4
04-May-2022    5
dtype: int64

In [29]: seriesB
Out[29]: 
01-May-2022    1
02-May-2022    2
02-May-2022    3
02-May-2022    2
02-May-2022    3
03-May-2022    4
04-May-2022    5
dtype: int64
```

Does anyone know why seriesB has the additional rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `Series` called series has duplicate values in the index - namely `02-May-2022` so when you use that same value for a lookup in `.loc[]` it matches twice:

```
series.loc["02-May-2022"]

02-May-2022    2
02-May-2022    3
```

If you have the lookup value in `.loc[]` twice then it will return 4 rows (2x2 rows):

```
series.loc[["02-May-2022","02-May-2022"]]

02-May-2022    2
02-May-2022    3
02-May-2022    2
02-May-2022    3
```

The `.dropna()` has no effect in your example data.

As a side note, you can use this capability of `.loc[]` to duplicate values if needed:

```
series.loc[["01-May-2022","01-May-2022","01-May-2022","01-May-2022"]]

01-May-2022    1
01-May-2022    1
01-May-2022    1
01-May-2022    1
```

Think of this as an index lookup instead of masking.

---

Deleting a row in a `Series` that contains an `NA` index value should work like you intended - with no dups:

```
dates = ["01-May-2022", "02-May-2022", np.nan, "03-May-2022", "04-May-2022"]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
series = pd.Series(values, index=dates)
series

01-May-2022    1
02-May-2022    2
NaN            3
03-May-2022    4
04-May-2022    5

seriesB = series.loc[series.index.dropna()]
seriesB

01-May-2022    1
02-May-2022    2
03-May-2022    4
04-May-2022    5
```

Comment: Thanks @jch. Is there a recommend way to drop rows missing an index value without using this type of lookup & causing duplicates?

Comment: When I try it, it works like I think you want it to work.  I updated my answer to reflect that.  Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: `seriesB = series[~series.index.isna()]` should work.

Comment: Thanks @jch and @Joooeey -- these examples help clarify the behavior. It's interesting to me that `series.loc[series.index.dropna()]` duplicates identical indices whereas `series.loc[~series.index.isna()]` does not.

Comment: @AndrewRonaldFriedman My point was that I do not think that `series.loc[series.index.dropna()]` duplicates identical indices.  I cannot recreate the duplication behavior.  I believe my example at the end of my answer demonstrates that.  What am I missing? How can I recreate the duplicates situation that you have?

Comment: @jch sorry for the confusion. I was referring to a situation similar to my original question where the index contains identical values. For example `dates = ["01-May-2022", "01-May-2022", np.nan, "03-May-2022", "04-May-2022"]
    ...: values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ...: series = pd.Series(values, index=dates)`.